# Are there existing tools to help track a tag and gather statistics?

Tags: support, data-explorer, api, moderator-tools, scraping

Lots of tags are monitored by the people/companies who helped build those products.

Are there existing tools to help gather basic statistics about a tag? Such as:

- Number of questions asked per (day, month, year)
- Number of questions with a response
- Number of questions with a response marked as answer
- Number of questions without a response, but with a comment
- Number of questions without a response or a comment
- Average time between question and response marked as answer
- etc...

These are the kinds of questions I ask on the tags I monitor, and before I build a tool myself, I thought it would make sense to first check if something like this exists.

Search Engines have not given any good results. I am familiar with [Stack Exchange Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries). Is this the tool I should be using? How about external tools which use the [Stack Exchange API](https://api.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some of this info can already be found in existing SEDE queries:

- Number of Questions per Time Period:

  - Day: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=questions+asked+per+day
  - Month: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=questions+asked+per+month
  - Year https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=questions+asked+per+year

Some of this info can be found on the Q&A website itself when searching ([css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) tag used for these, switch to whatever tag you like):

- Number of Questions with Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+answers%3A1.
- Number of Questions with Accepted Answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3Ayes
- Number of Questions with no Answers (the existence or lack of comments would require a SEDE query): https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss%5D+answers%3A0

But pretty much all of these metrics can be found via the API by writing a SEDE query or queries.

Comment: Note: SEDE doesn't include deleted questions, there's a table with deleted question metadata, but I'm unsure if any query use them.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will take this as to say there are no external tools that work 'out of the box' for these purposes, and to use Stack Exchange Data Explorer for these kinds of queries.

Comment: Handy. Any idea how to limit to those that aren't closed or flagged as duplicate? `[css] answers:0`

Comment: @KScandrett Can't check pending flags, I don't think those are exposed, but you can add `closed:no` to the query to show only open questions.